# Couldn’t understand the output of this code?

Tags: java, string, overloading, stringbuffer

```
     public class Test {

   public void method(String param)
   {
       System.out.println("String version");
   }

   public void method(StringBuffer param)
   {
       System.out.println("String Buffer");
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Test test=new Test();
       test.method(null);
   }
}
```

This code result is compilation error says “reference to method is ambiguous”

```
    public class Test
{
    public void method1(Object param)
    {
        System.out.println("Object Version ");
    }

    public void method1(String param)
    {
        System.out.println("String Version ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test test=new Test();
        test.method1(null);
    }
}
```

This code result is “String Version”

Actually I can’t understand the result of second piece of code. Why don’t both piece of code has the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case,

`null` is a subtype of every other reference type. 
So, compiler finds ambiguity in deciding which method to call..

In second case, it finds more specific object for `null` which happens to be String. Hence it calls `method1` and prints `String Version`

Comment: But also Object accept null value. Why does compiler choose String??

Comment: String extends object and thus is more specific

Comment: @Yasmin [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) tells that compiler always chooses most specifi method. String is more specific that Object.

Comment: and as String and StringBuffer both of them extend from Object class the compiler counters ambiguous Right??

Comment: @Yasmin: Exactly. The compiler wouldn't know which was more specific so would throw up an error.